# Troubleshoot USB RFID desktop reader ACS ACR1281U

Tags: usb, rfid

I have a USB desktop reader "ACR1281U" which is a basic keyboard emulation reader. When you "swipe" the card it'll output it's ID and run a ENTER-command.

When I plug this into my Raspberry Pi it'll work from time to time with 1-2 swipes and sometimes it doesn't work at all. This is with all default drivers - I haven't installed anything else then just input the USB-device into my R-Pi.

First I thought that the official driver from ACS could/would solve this so I went to their website http://www.acs.com.hk/en/driver/36/acr128u-dual-interface-smart-card-reader/ but found out that they only have their driver (.deb) package as i386 and amd64.

Do I really need to official driver or can I somehow troubleshoot my device as it is now? When I boot up I can see that the RPi detects the correct USB device on input. Is there something I can do to troubleshoot this further?

Thanks

Comment: Could this be a power supply problem? Maybe the R-Pi doesn't have the juice to power the USB-device on it's own?

Comment: adding to the comment above how is it connected to the Pi? Have you tried connecting it through a powered hub?

Comment: Right now it's just connected to one of the standard 2 USB ports. I'll try and get a powered hub today and see if that'll help with the power supply to rule that out. Thank you.

Comment: I got a D-Link DUB-H7 USB hub and I can see during the R-Pi load screen that it detects the 5-port hub but for some reason my connected devices (like the Reader) doesn't work at all (it's not lit/powered). Can there be a problem with the USB-hub? Can I troupleshoot that or should I order this instead http://shop.pimoroni.com/products/pihub?

Comment: It was the USB power supply! I got another one with different voltage and now it's working perfectly.

Comment: @naboovalley Can you post your code somewhere? I'm having issues with another ACS device: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/33875/raspberry-pi-and-the-acs-acr1252u-usb-nfc-card-reader

Comment: @sandy problem wasn't my  code, it was the power supply. se below.

Comment: @naboovalley I understand this, but personally I'm stuck with the code part, and some sample code would be useful for me.

Comment: @sandy I have no code-sample since this wasn't part of my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RFID card reader can't be powered by the R-Pi but needs it's own power source. Connecting the reader through an externaly powered USB-hub will make the reader work.

Comment: What version of the Raspberry Pi were you using?